# Swiper widget itemCount change from infinite

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a list of  assistants with the Swiper Library.
But the problem is that from the assistants list I'm receiving only 1 or 2 instances, but the Swiper is repeating those users infinite times. I'm wondering how to limit it to the number of assistants.
this is my code:

```
    child: Swiper(
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayDelay: 2000,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  "host${_user.img}"),
              radius: 35.0,
            ),
            Text(
              assistants[index].username,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      scale: .01,
      itemCount: assistants.length,
      viewportFraction: .18,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually it is already building only 2 items (or better say its building items according to your assistants list length) **But** the thing is that its looping it by default. So if you want it to end up somewhere you can easily set the loop property to false. Try the code below:

```
  child: Swiper(
  autoplay: true,
  loop: false,  //this is the property that prevents the swiper from looping
  autoplayDelay: 2000,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              "host${_user.img}"),
          radius: 35.0,
        ),
        Text(
          assistants[index].username,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
  scale: .01,
  itemCount: assistants.length,
  viewportFraction: .18,
),
```

Also here's a list of Swiper library properties that you can have a look for any 
further changes.

[image]

Comment: Don't worry about it. It happens for the continuous work and lower concentration. Try to take a break sometimes :)